# generate slug url using rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

Based on [this tutorial](http://rubysnippets.com/2013/02/04/rails-seo-pretty-urls-in-rails/), I've created a slug url but when I click show or add post it showing error as :

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
Couldn't find Post with id=testing-seo-url
```

Instead of taking slug it is taking as `id`. where I have to make changes make this work.
Here is my controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
    end
end
```

And here is my model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
end
```

This is just a scaffold. I didn't create any other controller.

Comment: probably, after installation of the gem, you could run `Post.find_each(&:save)` in `rails console`, of course after `rake db:migrate` to be added slug to `Posts` table.

Comment: yea did both but same error. I am having slug column in my table with `url-separated-with-hifen-like-this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved

```
def set_post
      @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```